# Python : Geomspace and Logspace do not return true boundaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am trying to make an array in logscale with python 3 and numpy.

I have an issue with the boudaries of my array, the returned array give a lower limit **below** the limit I want.

For instance :

```
In : a = np.array(379/19)
In : x = np.geomspace(a, 20)
In : x[0] >= a
Out: False
```

Whereas with linspace it works :

```
In : y = np.linspace(a, 20)
In : y[0] >= a
Out: True
```

Is it an known issue with logspace and geomspace ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Thanks to Warren Weckesser answer in a previous post, to ensure that my array have the right boudary I can use : `x[0] = a`, but I am wondering if there is a cleaner answer to this issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python : Geomspace (np.logspace like) does not respect boudaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44136851/python-geomspace-np-logspace-like-does-not-respect-boudaries)

Comment: close this version as a duplicate of the other, since that has more details and comments

Answer (score 1):

You're essentially [testing floats for equality](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/02/25/comparing-floating-point-numbers-2012-edition/), which is a bad idea.

```
a    is 19.94736842105263
x[0] is 19.947368421052627
y[0] is 19.94736842105263
```

So they are very close, but not identical.  This is how floating-point math typically works, and you can't generally guarantee whether one will be greater or less than the other, due to rounding error.

What are you trying to do with these boundaries, exactly?